# renewable resource vs consumable resource in operating system

Tags: operating-system, deadlock, mutual-exclusion

What are renewable resource & consumable resource in operating system field?
I read these while i read about Concurrency , mutual exclusion & deadlock , exactly in : operating systems:internals & design principles for william stalling .

Answer (score 2):

Deadlock comes from contention between processes (or threads) for resources. So, to understand deadlock we need to understand resources.

**Reusable resources**

The resources that can be reused again. Examples include *Processors, I/O channels, main and secondary memory, files, databases, and semaphores.*

**Consumable resources**

The resources that are depleted after the use by a process. Examples include *Hardware interrupts, Unix signals, pthread_cond_signal calls, messages, and information in I/O buffers.*

[Source](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/cop5611.S03/deadlock.html)